# Java 8 Stream List into map with identical values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm in a bizarre situation. Is there anyway to stream a List to a map with identical values?

i.e.

let `a` be of type `Map< Integer, List< String > >`

let's say `b` is just a list of integers that correspond to the keys of `a`.

```
b.stream().map(x ->
    a.get(x).stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(i -> i, x);
        )
);
```

I want a map where all the values are an `x` and all the keys are from the values in `b`.

The above function is supposed to return a `Stream< List< Map< String, Int > > >` (obviously it doesn't work)

Comment: Can you show sample input and output data?

Comment: Your posted code should produce a stream of maps, each mapping all keys to a single value. I'm not sure why you would want that, or where the list comes into the result.

Comment: The second value in `toMap` needs to be a lambda as well `Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> x)`

Comment: The above looks to me like it'd create a **stream** of `Map<String, Int>`. You could make that into a `List<Map<String, Int>>` but adding another `collect` call before the final `;`. Not sure what it'd mean for it to be a stream of list of map - that seems like one too many collection/stream.

Comment: @flakes thank you. exactly what I needed.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. If all you want is “a map where … all the keys are from the values in b”, you probably want just `Map< Integer, List< String > > result = b.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(i -> i, a::get) );`, assuming that “`x`” is the `List<String>`. Otherwise, you should first describe your actual problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second value in the `toMap` method needs to be a lambda as well *(ie it needs to satisfy the interface `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`, where `T` is the type for objects in the `b` stream and `U` is the type for values in the resulting map)*:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> a = ...
List<Integer> b = ...
Stream<Map<String, Integer>> c = b.stream().map(x ->
        a.get(x).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> x)));
```